# If button is clicked hide button for user

Tags: custom-button

I am trying to write some js for salesforce to hide a button once it has been clicked for that specific user. I have hit a hurdle....any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code;

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}

var newIdea = [];

var a = new sforce.SObject("TLF_Idea__c");

a.id ="{!Idea__c.Id}";
a.Total_Votes__c = {!Idea__c.Total_Votes__c} + 1;
newIdea.push(a);

result = sforce.connection.update(newIdea);

window.location.reload();

if({!$User.Total_Votes__c}} >= + 1){
    location.replace("Thank you for your vote");
}
else{
    alert("Sorry, something has gone wrong.");
}
```

My thoughts are if the vote increase as a result of the click the button should be replaced with the thank you text.

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding your logic within something like this, which loops through the buttons and when it finds the button labelled 'test' it relabels it 'loading...'

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}

var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(btns, function(el) {
    // Do stuff with the element
    if(el.title=='test') {
         el.value = 'loading..'; return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your response...I am not to sure how I go about adding my code to the. All I want to do is once a vote has been submitted just hide the button.....

Comment: No problem. You could also disable the button or change other attributes as well.

Comment: So in regards to the code you have, how would I include that into my above code? I am not to sure what to do there....do I simply get rid of the last 6 lines from "if" to the closing bracket?

Comment: I added some revised code for your review.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked the suggestion provided into your code. I havent tested it but hope it gives you more clarity. The 'title' attribute on the custom button you add to your page layout is what you'll need to change for this to work. Just use firebug or chrome debugger to inspect the page elements on a detail view and confirm the title attribute there.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 

/* to hide the button */
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(btns, function(el) {
    // Do stuff with the element
    if(el.title=='<whatever the title of the button you want to hide is>') {
         el.style.display = 'none'; return false;
    }
});
/* end hide button */

var newIdea = []; 
var a = new sforce.SObject("TLF_Idea__c"); 
a.id ="{!TLF_Idea__c.Id}"; 
a.Total_Votes__c = {!TLF_Idea__c.Total_Votes__c} + 1; 
newIdea.push(a); 
result = sforce.connection.update(newIdea); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for doing that...unfortunately I got an unusual error advising me that that Total_Votes__c field does not exist when it does... the following works perfectly...but simply doesn't hide the button.  {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}

var newIdea = [];

var a = new sforce.SObject("TLF_Idea__c");

a.id ="{!TLF_Idea__c.Id}";
a.Total_Votes__c = {!TLF_Idea__c.Total_Votes__c} + 1;
newIdea.push(a);

result = sforce.connection.update(newIdea);

window.location.reload();

Comment: I reworked the code for you using what you just provided. Just set the if statement to whatever the title of your button is per previous dialogue.

Comment: Awesome the hide function works..when I go ride of the "window.location.reload();" because it was refreshing the page. It would be perfect if it hid the button for "User A" who has placed a vote altogether. Because when you go back in the button is there again....

Comment: you can do that. If you store the vote on the user record (via apex), then in your script merge the value you stored on user record into a js variable, then consider it in your IF statement.